# How to run multiple DC motors in different patterns?

Tags: arduino-mega, motor

I am a complete novice in programming and I hope someone could guide me here. I am doing a haptic research project, where 8 DC coin vibrating motors would be fitted on the fingers of subjects (excluding thumbs), and the subject has to respond the number of fingers they feel the vibrations on.

Every trial has to have a different pattern of outputs, say: in first trial, 4 motors are activated-motor 1, motor5, motor8 and motor 3. In a single trial, the motors have to have a common delay of 150 ms and 4 seconds break after next one starts.

**My question is, that in 8 motors, there are 255 different activation patterns possible. How do I define all these 255 patterns and randomise their sequence?
I am using the mega board and connecting each motor to a PWM pin and all having a common ground.**

Here is a sample code with 3 such combinations (only seven motors are connected here):

```cpp
#define viboutpin 2
#define viboutpin1 3
#define viboutpin2 4
#define viboutpin3 5
#define viboutpin4 6
#define viboutpin5 7
#define viboutpin6 8


void setup() {
     pinMode(viboutpin,OUTPUT);// define a pin as output
     pinMode(viboutpin1,OUTPUT);
     pinMode(viboutpin2,OUTPUT);
     pinMode(viboutpin3,OUTPUT);
     pinMode(viboutpin4,OUTPUT);// define a pin as output
     pinMode(viboutpin5,OUTPUT);
     pinMode(viboutpin6,OUTPUT);  
}
       

void loop() {    
    digitalWrite(viboutpin,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin4,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin5,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin6,HIGH);
    delay(150);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin4,LOW);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin5,LOW);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin6,LOW);
    delay(2000);
    
    digitalWrite(viboutpin2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin6,HIGH);
    delay(150);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin6,LOW);
    delay(2000);
    
    digitalWrite(viboutpin4,HIGH);
    delay(150);
    digitalWrite(viboutpin4,LOW);
    delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not generate a psuedo random number from 0 to 255 and use it as a code for which motors are to be activated - bit 0 == viboutputpin0, etc.? Then one function can look at each bit in turn and activate that motor if the bit is set, delay, and stop the motors.

You'll probably want to test your code with a few pre-defined test patterns instead of the random ones, and once you're satisfied that it works, randomly seed the random number generator so your project will generate a different pattern each time. One way to do that is to ask via terminal for the operator to click the 'Send' button (or tap the space bar if you're using a separate terminal emulator that sends key by key). Measure the time from the request to the response in microseconds, discard the 2 or 3 least significant bits of the result and keep the next 8. The micros() function's resolution is 4 usec at 16 MHz, is the reason for discarding those 2 lower bits.